# Customizing dateAxis of a PrimeFaces chart

Tags: jsf, primefaces, axis-labels

I have a problem with the DateAxis in a Primefaces LineChartModel. The chart gets fed with values for each hour per day, the x - axis range is the 21th from one month to the 20th next month, its all good but primefaces automatically adds a label for the 21th at the end of the x axis, which is totally ok usually because its for the values from 20th to 21th, but unfortunately not everybody agrees with me and I need to get rid of the label (not the data of course)- I just don't know how since PrimeFaces automatically adds the last label itself, I've tried different ticks but actually I go with "1 day"

I cannot upload pictures yet but it is like this:

21th 22th...            19th 20th 21th

but should be like

21th 22th...            19th 20th

(people can go a period forward or backward onclick)

maybe someone can help

edit:

What I tried: 
-instead of getting the Period from 21.mm.yyyy 01:00 to 20.mm.yyyy 00:00
changed it to:  21.mm.yyyy 01:00 to 20.mm.yyyy 23:00
- setting the axis tick to 24
- switching from dateaxis to linearaxis didn't work out well since its a multi-line chart and a dateaxis just perfect does the job, it just needs to be customized

Comment: iam actually looking for a way to hide the label visually, the data is all correct

Comment: To move the X Axis i used css to move the part of the Diagram out of the viewable Field.. this is not a good solution but i did not found another solution.